# The Drive Activity function is no longer usable in version v3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-activity-api

In Google Drive api v2:

> [Resource: DriveActivity](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/driveactivity)
> A single Drive activity comprising one or more Actions by one or more Actors on one or more Targets. Some Action groupings occur spontaneously, such as moving an item into a shared folder triggering a permission change. Other groupings of related Actions, such as multiple Actors editing one item or moving multiple files into a new folder, are controlled by the selection of a ConsolidationStrategy in the QueryDriveActivityRequest.

In V3:
It may have been changed or deleted, who can give me more information?

Answer (score 1):

[Google drive Activity API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2) is not the same as [Google Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk) which has a new version called [Google Drive API V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)

As far as i can see there is no Google drive Activity API v3. Nor as far as i can see is [Google drive Activity API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2) deprecated.

I think you have confused your apis and should just continue to use [Google drive Activity API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2) for activity information as this is out of scope for either of the Google drive API's which are file storage only.